# Irreducible elements and unique factorization domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $P=\{\frac{a}{3^n} : a \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

a) Which elements are irreducible in $P$: 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 15?

b) Find out, which one of rings: $ P$, $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}]$, $P[x]$ is a unique factorization domain.

My guess for a) is 4 and 10. Could you give me any hints for b)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) $4=\frac{2}{1}\cdot\frac21$ and similarly for $10$. On the other side, $5$ is irreducible, $6=\frac21\cdot\frac31$ and $\frac31$ is invertible in $P$, so $6$ is also irreducible, and similarly for $15$. It remains $9=3^2$ which is invertible in $P$.

b) $P$ is a UFD as a ring of fractions of a UFD; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140584/about-the-localization-of-a-ufd). We also have that $P[x]$ is a UFD; see [here](http://www.math.uwo.ca/~srankin/courses/4123/2011/r_ufd_r[x]_ufd.pdf).

Comment: $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is well known as not being a UFD for this simple reason: $2\cdot 3=(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$.