# The ring $K[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]][x_1^{-1},\ldots,x_n^{-1}]$ is UFD?

Tags: commutative-algebra, power-series, unique-factorization-domains

It is well known that the ring of formal power series over a field $K[[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]]$ is an UFD. My question is the following: the ring $K[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]][x_1^{-1},\ldots,x_n^{-1}]$ is also UFD? I was not able to find any reference on such a result.

Comment: Yes, it is a UFD because [the localization of a UFD is also a UFD](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/140584/11653).

Comment: But it is a localization?! With respect to which multiplicatively closed set? Maybe the set of monomials in $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$?

Comment: The set of monomials will work perfectly, or you can think of it as a sequence of $n$ localizations with respect to each of the variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.