# Using the field of fraction F[x] to prove that in R[x], every irreducible element is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can we show that any irreducible element in $R[x]$ is prime where R is a unique factorization domain? Note that we should not assume that R[x] is also a unique factorization domain as the question itself is an intermediate step in the proof. A hint is to look at the field of fractions $F$ or $R$ and use the fact that $F[x]$ is a UFD. However I am not sure why this would help us. I think there might be some properties of $F[x]$ that I am unaware of.

Comment: Take a look at "Gauss' Lemma"!

Comment: See [Nagata's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/140622/242) for a more general perspective.

Comment: @FlipTack so gauss lemma gives us that if f is irreducible in R[x] then it is also irreducible in F[x], and since F[x] is a UFD, every irreducible element is prime, now can we conclude that being prime in F[x] implies prime in R[x]?

Comment: There's a bit of fiddling around with the definition of a 'primitive polynomial', and proving that a few logical results actually hold, but yes that is the general idea :)

Comment: For intuition, you can consider R[X] and Q[X], and it basically comes down to 'clearing denominators' of polynomials in Q[X] to get polynomials in R[X].